# sql server 2012 rip?

Tags: sql

На сервере стоит sql server 2012, но в свое время при установке не поставили компонент репликации.
Перерыв весь интернет, включая майкрософт, найти установочный пакет не удалось.

Скажите, если обновить сервер до 2014/16 версии, лицензия слетит ? 
Или как быть, если на офф сайте уже стерли все файлы обновлений ?

Comment: Обратиться с вопросом в поддержку. Странно, что вы не используете эту уже оплаченную вами услугу.

Comment: Сервер устанавливали другие люди и не включили этот компонент тогда..

Comment: Какая разница кто устанавливал? В цену лицензии входит право выносить мозг поддержке. Вы зачем-то самостоятельно ищите ответы на публичных ресурсах. За такси заплатил, а сам не поехал, как в анекдоте.